# Get Woocommerce rest api return product object by slug

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

i wanted my wordpress woocommerce to return products by slug to frontend. the function work it will return by if i enter slugs, but however this wont return any gallery images only id. so i can get the url but i cant make it the same object like **wp-json/wc/v3/products**, so how do i make it return like the same object ?

```
wp-json/wc/v3/products/category/brand1
```

my functions

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'wc/v3', '/products/category/(?P<slug>[^/]+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'wc_get_products_by_category',
    ) );
} );

function wc_get_products_by_category( $data ) {

    $products = array();
    $images_data = new stdClass;
    $images_data->images = new stdClass;

    try {
    $p = wc_get_products(array('status' => 'publish', 'category' => $data['slug']));
      foreach ($p as $product) {
          $products_data[] = array($product->get_data());
          $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();

          foreach ($attachment_ids as $position => $attachment_id) {
              $attachment = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'full');
              if (!is_array($attachment)) {
                  continue;
              }
              $images_data->images->src = current($attachment);
          }
          $products[] = $images_data;
      }
    }catch(HttpClientException $e){
        die("Reaspone wc_get_products_by_category : failure + $e");
    }

    return new WP_REST_Response($products, 200);
}
```

Return from postman
**wp-json/wc/ve/products**

```
"images": [
            {
                "id": 42,
                "date_created": "2022-01-18T16:16:45",
                "date_created_gmt": "2022-01-18T16:16:45",
                "date_modified": "2022-01-18T16:16:45",
                "date_modified_gmt": "2022-01-18T16:16:45",
                "src": "http://localhost:3080/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/IMG_1669.jpg",
                "name": "IMG_1669",
                "alt": ""
            },
            {
                "id": 41,
                "date_created": "2022-01-18T16:15:58",
                "date_created_gmt": "2022-01-18T16:15:58",
                "date_modified": "2022-01-18T16:16:59",
                "date_modified_gmt": "2022-01-18T16:16:59",
                "src": "http://localhost:3080/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/images.jpeg",
                "name": "images",
                "alt": ""
            }
        ],
```

my function return : **wp-json/wc/v3/products/category/brand1**

```
[
    {
        "images": {
            "src": "http://localhost:3080/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/wedding_gaiwan_set.jpg"
        }
    },
    {
        "images": {
            "src": "http://localhost:3080/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/wedding_gaiwan_set.jpg"
        }
    }
]
```

i want the format be like the products

```
"images": [
       {
         // images 1
         "src": "/path/images"
       },
       {
         // images 2
         "src": "/path/images"
       },
]
```

also if anyone have a better how it somehow can return the same object like getting products, hopefully you could share some of your idea. cause i feel worry with this nested foreach.